# How do I get Figma to list things NOT backwards?

Tags: figma

Thing are backwards.
Stuff on top of page are is listed on the bottom.
Things listed in horizontal frames are listed right(first) to left(last).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The layers are shown in the correct order. They aren't backwards.

I think you are perhaps misunderstanding the concept of layers in graphic design software. The following explanation isn't just limited to Figma, but also applies for example to other software such as Adobe Illustrator, Adobe Photoshop, Adobe XD, GIMP, Inkscape, Krita, etc, etc.

Layers are not listed by their physical position on a page. Instead they are listed in the order in which they are added to the page. The lowest object (the first object created) will be at the bottom of the stack. The next object added will be above that, and so on.

Think of layers like a stack of transparencies, with each object on its own layer. This diagram is for Photoshop, but the concept is the same.

[image]

In graphic design software, it is possible to move or rearrange layers in the layers panel by clicking and dragging them to a new position. However, it's very important to remember that the position of layers may be crucial to a design. For example, if you place an object on top of another (in the layer stack), it may hide an object below.

Here's an example in Figma. As you can see, when I click and drag the ellipse layer above the star layer, the ellipse then covers part of the star.

[image]

Obviously, if your objects are not overlapping like this, then the order of the layers will not matter at all. You can then freely rearrange them as you would like.